# Hit as "arrive at, come to, reach" (a place, limit etc)

Tags: etymology, idioms, word-usage, colloquialisms

Do you have any idea how "hit" came to mean reach or arrive at a point, place, or limit and the like?

Oxford:

1. reach (a particular level, point, or figure) : "his career hit rock bottom"
2. arrive at or go to (a place): "we hit a diner for coffee and doughnuts"

Are there any restrictions to its usage this way that I should be aware of?

A few examples:

- [Hurricane Irma Florida path: What time will Irma hit Orlando and Miami?](https://www.express.co.uk/news/weather/851306/Hurricane-Irma-Florida-path-update-Orlando-Miami-USA-hurricane-track)
- various expressions: hit the road; hit the skids
- ["How can I not kill him?" Jack had hit his limit. I was nearing mine as well.](https://books.google.ro/books?id=prmXAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT120&dq=hit%20his%20limit&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=hit%20his%20limit&f=false)

My understanding of the word "hit", the senses above aside, is that it means strike, as in come physically, perhaps violently into contact with something. Might it be that from there it evolved to simply "come into contact"- or, better said- run into, come across ("strike/hit pay dirt" comes to mind), and from there evolved still?

Comment: The relevant definition in the full OED (**hit**, verb, section 2) is *To come upon, light upon, meet with, get at, attain to, reach one's aim, succeed, and the like,* of which they say ***This is the Old Norse sense**; but with the exception of the single late Old English instance in sense 11, **its exemplification in English as a whole is later**.* Sense 11 referred to there is the first one in that second section: *trans. To come upon, light upon, meet with, get at, reach, find, esp. something aimed at.*

Comment: The question would be clearer if you explain what you think the word meant before it "came to mean reach or arrive at a point".

Comment: all right. Will do.

Comment: @Daniel To hit as strike also means to reach the target. If you try to hit someone, but you fail to reach the target, you literally don't hit; you miss. Not sure what else there is to say.

Comment: @Mr Lister: So far as I can make out from the full OED entries, the *reach or arrive at a point* sense was the ***original*** meaning (first cite 1075, and I don't see the *strike with a blow* sense until at least a century later).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, so you're saying the question should have been asked in reverse: when did hit come to mean "strike" rather than just "arrive at". I would be OK with that.

Comment: @Mr Lister: From what I can understand of the OED entry, that would seem to be the case, yes. Their etymology for the verb says *Late Old English **hyttan** = Old Norse **hitta** to hit upon, light upon, **meet with**, Swedish **hitta**, Danish **hitte** to hit, **find***. Presumably we Brits being a pugnacious lot, we had greater need for the ***clout, wallop, belt, whack, bash, clobber*** sense. Or perhaps we just misunderstood what the Viking invasions were all about (they didn't come to ***hit*** us with Danegeld; they just came to ***meet*** us! :)

Comment: Amp up _meet_ and you get a collision. Hit a target and you can hit Vegas around 11.

Comment: "Hit a limit" may also refer to analog meters, where the moveable indicator literally strikes a post at the far end of the dial.

Answer (score 1):

> To happen or occur, to become suddenly apparent to (a person), to come or light upon; meet with; find

As in:

> The storm [**hit**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hit) without warning. The reason for his behavior
>   **hit** me and made the whole episode clear.

[**hit**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hit) etymology